# Call a class method in an after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

That is may be a stupid point, but I don't find the solution.

I have a simple model with a class method `update_menu` and I want that it is called after each save of instance.

```
Class Category
  attr_accessible :name, :content


  def self.menu
     @@menu ||= update_menu
  end

  def self.update_menu
     @@menu = Category.all
  end
end
```

So what is the correct syntax to get the `after_filter` call `update_menu`?

I tried:

```
after_save :update_menu
```

But it looks for the method on the instance (which does not exist) and not on the class.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it an instance method by removing `self`.

```
# now an instance method
def update_menu
   @@menu = Category.all
end
```

It doesn't make much sense to have an `after_save` callback on a class method. Classes aren't saved, instances are. For example:

```
# I'm assuming the code you typed in has typos since
# it should inherit from ActiveRecord::Base
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end

category_one = Category.new(:name => 'category one')
category_one.save  # saving an instance

Category.save # this wont work
```

Comment: You're right for the inheritance, I just type it to give the content. However, it is a question of taste ;-) no? to keep the method at the class level instead of the instance level. Since it only updates a class variable. Is there no way to specify that it is a class method in the after_save? You always have to rely on an instance method?

Comment: You're thinking about the problem in the wrong direction. Yes, you're updating a class variable but the callback fires after an **instance**  is saved. It's a callback on an instance variable...not a callback on a class because it's not possible to "save" a class.

Answer (score 7):

```
after_save :update_menu

def updated_menu
  self.class.update_menu
end
```

this will call the class update_menu method

Comment: Instead of defining the method, you can also use delegate:
`delegate :update_menu, to: :class`
and then define the using the method:
`after_save :update_menu`

Answer (score 5):

```
after_save 'self.class.update_menu'
```

Rails will evaluate a symbol as an instance method.  In order to call a class method, you have to pass a string which will be evaluated in the correct context.

NOTE:  This only works with rails 4.  See Erez answer for Rails 5.

Comment: Passing string to define callback is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1 without replacement